# Swift - Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' to 'NSNumber' when fetching from CollectionGroup Firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, casting

I'm fetching values from Firestore and I need to fetch all sub-collections of a collection, therefore I'm using CollectionGroup. When I was specifying the whole path collection(name).document(id).collection(name) I was able to get the values no problem, however, when I changed to collectionGroup(ID) the results come I can't get them to be cast/converted to Double.
I'm adding the whole code bellow

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
import CoreLocation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class MapaRiscoSegVC: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var tupleRiskArray: [(lat: Double, long: Double)] = []
    var tupleSecurityArray: [(lat: Double, long: Double)] = []
    var db: Firestore!
    var userID: String?
    var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
    let myQueue = DispatchGroup()

    @IBAction func riscoBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //show risk occurrences

    }

    @IBAction func seguridadeBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //show security occurrences
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        db = Firestore.firestore()
        //Location Manager code to fetch current location
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
         if let user = user {
           // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project.
             self.userID = user.uid
             print(self.userID!, "user ID firebase")
         }
        myQueue.enter()
        myQueue.enter()
        fetchAllAlerts()
        myQueue.leave()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //adding the markers
        let seconds = 3.0 //improve this part
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
            self.addMarkers()
        }
        myQueue.notify(queue: .main) {
            //self.addMarkers()
        }

    }

    func addMarkers() {
        for location in self.tupleRiskArray {
            let latitude = location.lat
            let longitude = location.long
            let marker = GMSMarker()
            marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: UIColor(displayP3Red: 242/255, green: 202/255, blue: 142/255, alpha: 1.0))
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:latitude, longitude:longitude)
            marker.map = self.mapView
            self.bounds = self.bounds.includingCoordinate(marker.position)
        }
        let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(self.bounds, withPadding: 50)
        self.mapView.animate(with: update)
    }

    //Location Manager delegate
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations.last
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom: 17.0)
        //map initiation code
        self.mapView.camera = camera
        self.mapView?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        self.mapView?.animate(to: camera)
        self.mapView?.settings.myLocationButton = true
        //Finally stop updating location otherwise it will come again and again in this delegate
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    //fetch all lat&long pairs from Alertas Collection
    func fetchAllAlerts() {
        tupleRiskArray.removeAll() //make it clean
        //fetch from firebase
        db.collectionGroup("alertas-disparados").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    //print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data()["longitude-inicial"]!)")
                        let lat = document.data()["latitude-inicial"]
                        let long = document.data()["longitude-inicial"]
                        self.tupleRiskArray.append((lat, long)) <--- ERROR HERE: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' to 'NSNumber
----> tried casting as! Double, but failed saying found nil while unwrapping optional


                    }
                }
            print(self.tupleRiskArray)
        }

    }


}
```

But if try this(code bellow), it works fine, but I need not just from one document inside that root collection, I need all subcollections of all documents:

```
    func fetchAllAlerts() {
        tupleRiskArray.removeAll() //make it clean
        //fetch from firebase
       db.collection("Alertas").document(self.userID!).collection("alertas-disparados").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                  for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                      let lat = document.data()["latitude-inicial"] as! Double
                      let long = document.data()["longitude-inicial"] as! Double
                      self.tupleRiskArray.append((lat, long)) <--- Works fine
                  }
               }
            print(self.tupleRiskArray)
        }

    }
```

So I'd like some help solving this casting/conversion issue
Any help is welcome =)

Comment: Please be aware that a collection group query will query you **all** documents among **all** subcollections with the same name, not just the one you were querying before.  You might be getting a document from a different subcollection of the same name, and it probably contains a string instead of a number.  I suggest trying to find that specific document and correcting it.

Comment: that was the exact problem! thank you so much!